# Parameter "" for route "" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL

Tags: php, regex, symfony, twig

I have this Facade entity, everytime I try to modify a form where my below twig is included, it returns this error :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "buildings_id" for route "addFacade" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.").
```

My controller action :

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/card", name="business_card", methods="GET|POST|DELETE", defaults={"business_id"=1})
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Business $business
 * @return Response
 */
public function show_card(Request $request, Business $business): Response
{

    $businessCard = $business->getBusinessCard();

    $formCard = $this->createForm(BusinessCardType::class, $businessCard);
    $formCard->handleRequest($request);

    if (($formCard->isSubmitted() && $formCard->isValid())) {

        $businessCard = $formCard->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($businessCard);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('business_card', ['id' => $business->getId()]);
    }

    $dict = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J');
    return $this->render('business/card.html.twig', ['business' => $business, 'formCard' => $formCard->createView(), 'dict' => $dict]);
}
```

My twig template :

```
{% for buildingsInfo in business.businessCard.buildingsInfos %}
{% set idBuildingsInfo = idBuildingsInfo|merge([buildingsInfo.id]) %}
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-3" href="{{ path("addFacade",{"buildings_id": idBuildingsInfo[j] }) }}">Ajouter une façade</a>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried to dump my `idBuildingsInfo` variable, but all values of the array are numbers (no null values). I also tried to add a default value in my controller for parameter `buildings_id` but it does not seem to change anything.

Answer (score 2):

Read the error carefully

> Parameter "buildings_id" ... ("" given)

The parameter value you passed is null ("")

```
{{ path("addFacade",{"buildings_id": idBuildingsInfo[j] }) }}
```

**Is `j` defined?** or should that line look like this:

```
{{ path("addFacade",{"buildings_id": idBuildingsInfo["j"] }) }}
```

Comment: Hi, indeed j is defined, it is an increasing value, from 0 to the number of buildings. It is supposed to be `idBuildingsInfo[j]`

By using `dump()`, all values of `j`and ìdBuildingsInfo[j]` are defined and not null

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that the error might be pertinent to:

```
href="{{ path("addFacade",{"buildings_id": idBuildingsInfo[j] }) }}
```

and maybe we would `set` a variable for our `href`, and then escape those `"`s that are require to escape, and our code would look like:

```
{% for buildingsInfo in business.businessCard.buildingsInfos %}
{% set idBuildingsInfo = idBuildingsInfo|merge([buildingsInfo.id]) %}
{% set path = "\"addFacade\", {\"buildings_id\": idBuildingsInfo[j]" %}
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-3" href="{{ path }}">Ajouter une façade</a>
{% endfor %}
```

or somewhat similar.

Comment: The href should be the result of the twig path function (it was formatted correctly). Your suggestion does not call the function, and instead sets the href to the literal string of parameters that should be passed to the function '"addFacade",{"buildings_id": idBuildingsInfo[j]'. https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#path